# How can i replace GET[] with .html in URL using php

Tags: php

My current url: http://sarcasmbro.com/img.php?id=1 
What i want: http://sarcasmbro.com/1.html 
Hello stackers, 
As shown above i have having problem using GET[] command. Can i change it and add extension .html or .php using PHP? I want to make a query of that number(id) too.

```
$url = 'http://sarcasmbro.com/1.html';
$data = parse_url($url);
$id = basename($data['path'], '.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for this using .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /img.php?id=$1 [L]
```